# array_map does not give an empty array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below line which takes a string, explodes it to an array by ',' and then trims any whitespace for each array item.

```
   $essentialArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $essential_skills));
```

However when `$essential_skills string = ""` `$essentialArray` will equal `Array ( [0] => )`

But I need it to equal `Array()` so that I can call `empty()` on on it.

Comment: `explode()` is your problem, not `array_map()`, as it will never give you an empty array in response, which seems to be what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`explode` return `Array ( [0] => )`, so you need to check your string before `array_map`

here is a one solution

```
   $exploderesult = $essential_skills ? explode(',', $essential_skills) : array();
   $essentialArray = array_map('trim', $exploderesult );
```

Answer (score 1):

That is normal and logical behavior of the function.

Look at it this way: what does the `explode()` call return? An array with a single element which is the empty string. The `array_map()` call does not change that at all.

So you might ask: why does `explode('')` result in an array with a single element which is the empty string? Well, *why not?* It takes the empty string and splits it at all comma characters in there, so exactly no times. That means the empty string stays unaltered. *But it does not magically vanish!*

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution here will be just [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) result array, like this:

```
$essentialArray = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $essential_skills)));
```

but proper way is:

```
if ($essential_skills === '') {
$essentialArray = [];
}
else {
$essentialArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $essential_skills));
}
```